# How to use "cache" method of Mono

Tags: caching, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, webflux

I'm a beginner of spring webflux. While researching I found some code like:

```
Mono result = someMethodThatReturnMono().cache();
```

The name "cache" tell me about caching something, but where is the cache and how to retrieve cached things? Is it something like caffeine?

Comment: Your mono is a rawtype - don’t do that. Read the docs please - every subscriber to a Mono would normally trigger a new subscription; when `cache` is called then once a value is returned, the same value will be returned to all subsequent subscribers. https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#cache--

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It cache the result of the previous steps of the Flux/Mono until the `cache()` method is called, check the output of this code to see it in action:

```java
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class CacheExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var mono = Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            System.out.println("Go!");
            return 5;
        })
        .map(i -> {
            System.out.println("Double!");
            return i * 2;
        });

        var cached = mono.cache();

        System.out.println("Using cached");

        System.out.println("1. " + cached.block());
        System.out.println("2. " + cached.block());
        System.out.println("3. " + cached.block());

        System.out.println("Using NOT cached");


        System.out.println("1. " + mono.block());
        System.out.println("2. " + mono.block());
        System.out.println("3. " + mono.block());
    }
}
```

output:

```
Using cached
Go!
Double!
1. 10
2. 10
3. 10
Using NOT cached
Go!
Double!
1. 10
Go!
Double!
2. 10
Go!
Double!
3. 10
```

Comment: But for how long by default does this `cache` work ?
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#cache--
`Once the first subscription is made to this Mono, the source is subscribed to and the signal will be cached, indefinitely. This process cannot be cancelled.`

It's `indefinitely` ?

Comment: yes, it is. It doesn't have a time to live, this is used for different use cases. Imagine during the handling of a request for an http server, or during the running of a batch you have to access the same calculation multiple time, but you want to calculate it only once.

Comment: ok, but when i use HTTP request with other param value will the cache return the same result ? For example `calculations` are done based on some kind of param that is provided in http request.

Comment: nope I meant calculations in the scope of the same HTTP request, not shared among multiple HTTP requests. To implement a cache across different requests you need some other caching mechanism, the Mono/Flux cache is something also named **memoization** in other contexts

Comment: I had a use-case where my service made a REST call then:
1. do some calculation and save to db.
2. do some other calculations and return to user.
I cached the response and seperately used .subscribe() for saving to db. This made db operation done on background while user have the response without wait for db ops to complete.
I was confused on using .cache() but then @rascio 's line : `until the cache() method is called` made everything clear. Thanks Rascio.