# How to log the number of elements in a bodyToFlux()

Tags: spring-webflux

I have commented the count() method as it will block my method and not continue:

```
    public Flux<DdocumentBackofficeResponseRestDTO> queryPendingDocumentsToBeHashed() {
        Flux<DdocumentBackofficeResponseRestDTO> documents = webClient.get().uri("/pending-documents")
                .headers(h -> h.setBearerAuth(bearerToken)).retrieve()
                .onStatus(httpStatus -> !httpStatus.is2xxSuccessful(),
                        clientResponse -> handleErrorResponse(clientResponse))
                .bodyToFlux(DdocumentBackofficeResponseRestDTO.class);
//      documents.count().subscribe(c -> logger.info("Will request a total of {} files", c));
        return documents;
    }
```

I just want to log the number of elements that the flux returns once it has fetched and parsed the response. the code works and the documents are returned as a Flux which is later subscribe() in the caller method to process result... but, how can I log the number of elements?

Answer (score 0):

```
Flux<String> flux = Flux.just("abc", "xyz").cache();
Mono<Long> count = flux.count();

return flux.flatMap(f -> count.map(m -> Tuples.of(f, m)))
      .doOnNext(t -> System.out.println("Count: "+ t.getT2()))
      .map(Tuple2::getT1);
```

Remember to call `cache()` after your webClient `bodyToFlux(DdocumentBackofficeResponseRestDTO.class)`

FYI: [How to use "cache" method of Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67487077/how-to-use-cache-method-of-mono)